# パスワード世代管理の設定が上手くいかない

Tags: rhel

RHEL8でパスワードポリシーとして5世代まで保存するように設定したいですが、
設定内容が反映されず、困っています。

**設定内容:**

```
> authselect create-profile test-profile --base-on=sssd
> vi custom/test-profile/system-auth

password    sufficient   pam_unix.so sha512 shadow  try_first_pass use_authtok
　↓
password    sufficient   pam_unix.so sha512 shadow  try_first_pass use_authtok remember=2

> authselect select custom/test-profile --force
```

**設定結果のテスト:**

`passwd` でパスワードを変更してみたが、同じパスワードを何回設定しても、エラーが発生せず設定できてしまう。

上記結果になる理由をご存じのかたご教授をお願い致します。

Comment: passwd コマンドを実行したのは該当ユーザーでログインした状態、それとも root 権限のどちらでしょうか？

Comment: @cubick root権限でpasswdを実行したのですが、その場合はエラーにならないのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問のような世代管理は試した事がないので自信がありませんが、いわゆる "弱い" パスワードを一般ユーザーで設定しようとすると弾かれるのに対して、root 権限で対象ユーザーのパスワードとして設定することは可能なことがあったのでコメントしてみました。